# Doing the equivalent of a dependent t-test on a sample of correlation coefficients

Tags: correlation, group-differences, pooling, fisher-transform

I’m doing an analogy of the following study.

I take participants etc. and show them a picture of man 1 and have them rate his attractiveness and rate his intelligence just from his picture.  I then have each participant do the same task with man 2, man 3, on up to man 25.  So, ultimately, I end up with a correlation coefficient for each participant indicating how strongly that participant links attractiveness with intelligence in men.  Good.

Now, let’s say I take the same group of participants and have them do the same task with pictures of women … woman 1-woman 25.  Now I have a set of correlation coefficients telling me how strongly each participant links intelligence with attractiveness in women.

For clarity, my data could look like this:

```
Subject         r for male pics     r for female pics
1                   .74                 .42
2                   .44                 .12
3                   .43                 .22
```

Ultimately, I want to see if the mean $r$ for the male condition is different from the mean $r$ for the female condition.  (i.e., Can we predict predicted intelligence from attractiveness better for men than women?)  If those were just regular scores on a test, I would do a dependent t-test and be done.  But, they’re correlation coefficients.  I’ve found several different options ($r \rightarrow z$ transforms and then tests on the $z$'s, the Williams modification of the Hotelling test, etc) but have no idea how to decide which is the most appropriate one?

Comment: I would go for a permutation testing. Note however that your estimated correlation coefficients must carry standard errors, which further clouds the problem, so may be on top of permuting the labels (M/F participants), you may also want to may be bootstrap the ratings within each participant.

Comment: I feel like this might be the Fisher Z test for correlations?